# Add a method to the JQuery Librairy

Tags: javascript, jquery, import, module

I struggle (a lot) on something easy.

I want to add this librairy "JQuery Orthodox View Engine" (aka JOVN) to JQuery.
See: https://github.com/JocaPC/jquery-view-engine

In short: The Lib adds a new method to JQuery that can pick some JSON and render it in HTML TAGS that have a certain classname.
To do so, i have to import jquery (installed with NPM) and this JOVN Librairy (locally, the NPM package doesn't exist)

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import './jovnLib';
```

But the jovnLib.js is like this:

```
   (function($) {
  $.fn.view = function (obj, options) {
    if (!(typeof obj == 'object')) {
      ...
    }
    function loadSelect(nSelect, aoValues, name) {
      ...
    }

    function setElementValue(element, value, name) {
      ...
    }

    function bind(data, domNode, name) {
      ...
    } 

    function init(placeholder) {
      ...
    }

    var defaults = {
      ...
    };

    properties = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {});
  };
})(JQuery);
```

I understand that this import has side effects and need to find when it will run, the global variable jQuery, and i have the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined (for the last line of JOVN Module)
```

Do I might await import or use window.load = () ...
Thank you.

Comment: Modules can't refer to variables from the script that imports them. You need to import jQuery in `jovnLib`

Comment: Oh i see, i learn something new here. Thanks a lot! And have a nice day :)